# mysql_fetch_array not creating right elements?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: timein in time.php on line 42 Notice: Undefined index: timeout in time.php on line 45

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

$querytimeout = mysql_query("
    SELECT timein 
    FROM studentInfo
    WHERE name = '$name' 
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
    ")
    or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error());
    $querytimein = mysql_query("
    SELECT timeout
    FROM studentInfo
    WHERE name = '$name' 
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ")
    or die("Error querying database ".mysql_error());
while($minutestimein = mysql_fetch_array($querytimein)){
    $ltimein = $minutestimein['timein'];
    }
        while($minutestimeout = mysql_fetch_array($querytimeout)){
    $ltimeout = $minutestimeout['timeout'];
  }
  $timegone = $ltimein - $ltimeout; 
  echo $timegone;
  }
```

The problem is that `mysql_fetch_array()` isn't making `timein` or `timeout` an element of the array `$minutestimein`.

Comment: The querytimein has the field timeout in the query and the querytimeout variable has the field timein in the query. Then when you loop you search for those keys in the wrong variables.

Comment: Does the `timeout` column exist?

Comment: @Fred -ii- yes, both timein and timeout columns exist

Comment: See Mike's answer then; it makes sense.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you compare your queries to the fields that they are looking up, they don't match.

In the first query you select only `timeout` yet you try to reference `$minutestimein['timein']`.  You do the opposite in the second query.

Comment: So can i just make the first one select timeout and the second one select timein?

Comment: @user3429811 You just need to make sure you are trying to access the same fields that are actually in your select.

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries are redundant - they're fetching two different fields from the SAME record. Why not just run ONE query?

```
SELECT timein, timeout
FROM studentInfo
WHERE name = '$name'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

then

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$diff = $row['timeout'] - $row['timeout'];
```

Plus, there is literally **NO** point in using a `while()` loop to fetch your results. You've already limited your queries to returning only ONE row anyways, making the entire looping infrastructure useless.